# Remmina RDP connection remain in "Connecting to"

Tags: rdp, remmina

I try to connect with Remmina installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 to Windows Server 2016, but connection remain in "Connecting to"

[image]

I have no error and the port 3389 is correctly open (if I use other RDP client like rdesktop I can connect to server).

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not on the Windows side?

Comment: If I try to connect with rdesktop I can connect without problem (but rdesktop is so slowly)